# @EJB (lookup) not injected into JSF Managed Bean when bean comes from other jar

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb, jboss7.x

I have three applications deployed on JBoss 7.1: BaseApp, MyApp1, MyApp2. MyApp1 and MyApp depend on BaseApp (they use baseEJB.jar from BaseApp). I need to create a JSF managed bean where I want to lookup EJB using an @EJB annotation:

```
public class BaseAppBean {

    @EJB(lookup = "java:global/BaseApp/baseEJB/ManagerBean!com.ejb.manager.Manager")
    private Manager manager;

    public User getUser() {
        return manager.getUser();
    }

    ...
}
```

BaseAppBean will be used in both MyApp1 and MyApp2 so I decided it would be a good idea to put this class in BaseApp so both apps would get it from baseEJB.jar. But then I realized it does not work, it appeared that Manager EJB is not injected and NullPointerException is thrown in `getUser()` method.

After some trials I arrived to the three setups:

1. BaseAppBean placed in BaseApp, EJB injection with @EJB(lookup) annotation -> EJB not injected, manager == null
2. BaseAppBean placed in BaseApp, JNDI lookup instead of @EJB annotation -> EJB looked up properly, manager != null
3. BaseAppBean copied to both MyApp1 and MyApp2 (the duplication I hoped to avoid), EJB injection with @EJB(lookup) -> EJB correctly injected, manager != null

Hence my question, why is a setup described in 1. not working and 3. works correctly? In both cases BaseAppBean is created in the same web application context and the only difference is yet that in case 3 the class is in the same jar and in case 1 it is taken from other app's jar.

Comment: Is "Manager" the remote interface of the app? I'm not sure (had to check docs), but to communicate to a bean of an other application you need the remote interface. So add the @Remote annotation to the Manager interface and try again.

Comment: @rmertins, I don't suspect missing Remote annotation is a problem here. In option 3. it is working, MyApp is calling Manager even without Remote.

Comment: Yes because there is a local instance of the bean.